# Disable HDCP requirement on Chromecast

Tags: chromecast, rom, hdcp

We recently purchased a Chromecast to cast to our old (but very good) computer monitor as a substitute TV. Unfortunately, the monitor doesn't support HDCP, so the Chromecast OS refuses to display anything. Is there anything we can do in software (I hear root can be achieved) to disable this requirement?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no official way of doing that; if you consider the reason behind the HDCP requirement, you'll realize that Google will not enable any means to disable that.

Comment: I am aware of that. I am looking for something similar to the root escalation technique. i.e. Not something designed by Google.

Comment: Alright, going to mark this as accepted. You seem to be correct that there is no way.

Comment: HDCP provides no solution. Disabling HDCP, however, can be achieved. For ~$200 an HDFury2 is your best bet. Other, maybe cheaper, active adapters might strip HDCP.